# AForge download comes with no .dll files, how to use it?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I downloaded the image processing library AForge but there are no .dll files. Is there a way I can add reference to the library and use it in another c# project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `ALT -> T -> N -> O` (Or go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) and in the console type

```
Install-Package AForge -Version 2.2.5
```

The console will do the rest for you.

---

List of AForge NuGet packages are available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=AForge.NET)